Digital Ocean droplet 100% CPU usage - kauditd0
Does anyone know what kauditd0 service is ?
I’m encountering an issue with my Ubuntu server on a DigitalOcean Droplet, where the kauditd0 process is consuming 100% CPU (that never happened before). I’ve tried multiple methods to stop it, but it keeps reappearing. Here’s a detailed overview of the situation:
enter image description here
Background:
I have a NestJS API deployed on the Ubuntu Droplet. The kauditd0 process is using a high amount of CPU, making the server slow. I tried stopping kauditd0 manually via htop and it works, but it starts again using 100% CPU.
enter image description here

This question is similar to: How do I deal with a compromised server?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
